# Adding tap gesture to outlet collection

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uitapgesturerecognizer

Adding a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to my `UILabel`. I've created a `outlet collection` for the `UILabels` I want to add the tap event to. Here is my code:

`Outlet Collection Name = viewLabels`

```
let removeLabelTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(removeTagLabel(_:))) 

for label in (0..<viewLabels.count) {
   viewLabels[label].addGestureRecognizer(removeLabelTapGesture)
}

@objc func removeTagLabel(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print ("inside removeTagLabel")
}
```

I'm iterating through my outlet collection and adding the `gesture recognizer` to each `UILabel`. There was nothing being printed in the console.

After hitting my head for a few hours, I thought to try adding the `gesture recognizer` individually to each `UILabel`.

```
viewLabels[0].addGestureRecognizer(removeLabelTapGesture)
```

Now this works for one of the `UILabels`. Following this approach, if I do it individually it adds the `gesture event` to the last `UILabel` that I add the event to.

```
viewLabels[0].addGestureRecognizer(removeLabelTapGesture)
.
.
.
viewLabels[x].addGestureRecognizer(removeLabelTapGesture)  //Will add gesture event to this UILabel
```

Is there a way to add the `gesture recognizer` to each of my `UILabels`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of your approaches works. The problem is that your code tries to add the very same tap gesture recognizer to all the labels. You can’t do that, just like you yourself can’t be in New York and London at the same time.

Comment: If I had 3 `UILabels` I have to create 3 different `UITapGestureRecognizer` events and then add them individually? Even if the tap event is the same for each?

Comment: A tap gesture recognizer is not an event, it's an object that responds to events. Yes, each view that you want to respond to tap gestures needs its own tap gesture recognizer.

Comment: You **could** create a single tap gesture recognizer, attach it to the superview of all of your views, and then write custom code that uses the coordinates of the tap to figure out which subview was tapped (if any) but that's a lot of work, and you'd have to handle edge cases like tapping on the superview but not any of the views that you want to respond to taps. Just use a separate tap gesture recognizer for each view and be done with it.

Comment: Yeah, that's a lot work lol @DuncanC. Each view needs its own unique tap gesture recognizer. Did not know that - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A gesture should only be associated to only one view

```
for label in viewLabels {
    let removeLabelTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(removeTagLabel(_:))) 
    label.addGestureRecognizer(removeLabelTapGesture)
}
```

For example create an UIImageView , and add it multiple times to self.view , you will get it only once because it's a single object